# Classification (supervised learning) of expression data on pathway level

Tags: microarray, pathway

I was wondering if there is any way to apply classification algorithms (e.g random forest) on microarray data but not using the genes as predictors/features but the pathway they belong to.

The thing is that the expressions of the genes that belong to the same pathway should somehow, grouped together and transformed into a new value that will describe that pathway for each specific sample.

Let me give an example.

Assuming that we have `g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10` as genes
and `p1, p2, p3` as pathways.

And `g1, g2, g3` belong to `p1` while `g3, g4, g5, g6`belong to `p2` and `g2, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10` belong to `p3`

One thought is to calculate the mean expression of the above gene groups per sample and then run the classification algorithm on top of these values. But I would like to hear/read your opinion on such an approach and also your suggestions on using a different method to do this.

The final goal would be the extraction of the most significant classification predictors (pathways).

Comment: Do you assume that expression of genes are similar in pathways? Because in a real experiment they are not.

Comment: No, I don't want to assume something like that but I mentioned the mean in order to group the genes of each pathway. This approach might be totally wrong but that's why I posted here. To get feedback and different opinions.

Comment: My point is, that I haven't seen an algorithm that can transform the expression values of different genes into one value that represents a given pathway.

Comment: Oh ok. I see...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to incorrectly reinvent the activation Z-score produced by IPA or similar tools. I suggest you simply use that instead.

Comment: IPA is commercial. Isn't it? Can you provide me with free R-based ones to understand what exactly you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [GSVA](http://bioconductor.org/packages/GSVA) package. It allows to convert a matrix with `genes x Samples` to a `pathways x Samples` using several methods ssgsea, gage, gsva...

Afterwards you can use that matrix as input for differential expression of pathways or classification algorithms or whatever.

---

However it depends on the input of the "pathways" you give it. Make sure that the pathways are correct. Also consider that the pathway topology might change with conditions.